# Change cursor color after log out on ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: gnome, cursor

I've set my cursor color on `gnome-tweaks` to be `DMZ-Black`, which works fine when I log in and lock the computer. But, after I log out, the cursor color changes to white.

Is there a way to change the color of the cursor after log out?

My `gnome-tweaks` setting: 
[image: Click here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Ubuntu 18.04***

to set the cursor as `DMZ-Black` while in login screen..
it can be configured with the file `/etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults`

**Disclimer: if any spelling mistakes/ upper case, lower case or invalid entry edits to this file will stop accessing to GDM login screen.. of-course experts can revert the things back into normal.. proceed with your own..**

Open the file with your favorite text editor, mine is `gedit` so,

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults
```

and edit some of the content look like this

```
# Theming options
# ===============
#  - Change the GTK+ theme
[org/gnome/desktop/interface]
# gtk-theme='Adwaita'
cursor-theme='DMZ-Black'
```

Save the file close & reboot to see the cursor as you configured it in above file `DMZ-Black`

Pictures of Different Configurations:

[image]

[image]

[image]